# print attribute and element in xml with python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to print attributes and element text together in xml.

This is the following xml content I have:

```html
<nodes count="10" totalCount="14050">
<node foreignId="XX-WTRFGORXNWOAFG" foreignSource="XX" label="ABERTOXK01" id="10314" type="A">
<assetRecord>
<category>Unspecified</category>
<city>Boston</city>
<id>1795234</id>
<lastModifiedBy/>
<lastModifiedDate>2016-05-22</lastModifiedDate>
<manufacturer>Cisco Systems</manufacturer>
<modelNumber>ACE 4710</modelNumber>
<node>23456</node>
<operatingSystem>#NO_VALUE</operatingSystem>
<region>Eastern &amp; North America</region>
<serialNumber>XX</serialNumber>
</assetRecord>
<categories id="16" name="Class 1"/>
<categories id="812" name="Site_XX"/>
<categories id="69" name="Wireless"/>
<categories id="14" name="10min_collect"/>
<createTime>2016-09-21</createTime>
<labelSource>U</labelSource>
<lastCapsdPoll>2018-08-08</lastCapsdPoll>
<sysContact>ABERTOXK01</sysContact>
<sysDescription>ACE 4710 Application Control Engine Appliance</sysDescription>
<sysLocation>Boston</sysLocation>
<sysName>ABERTOXK01</sysName>
<sysObjectId>ERTYDDS</sysObjectId>
</node>
</nodes>
```

I am able to extract data from attribute like `<node> label =` and I can even extract data from the element such as `<manufacturer>Cisco Systems</manufacturer>`. But, I am not able to print them together in my code. I think I'm missing something very obvious. Please help!
This what I have tried so far:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import base64
urllib3.disable_warnings()
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

decoderuser = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(b'someusername')
username = decoderuser.decode("utf-8")

decoderpassword = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(b'somepassword')
password = decoderpassword.decode("utf-8")


print("Connection to OpenNMS is successful!")
response = requests.get("https://server/opennms/rest/nodes?limit=10", verify=False, auth=(username, password))
root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
items = root.findall('node/*')
for item in items:
    for child in root.iterfind('node'):
        #print(child.tag, child.attrib['label'])
        while item.find('city') is str:
            try:
                print((item.find('city')).text, (item.find('manufacturer')).text, child.attrib['label'])
            except: continue
```

I have 10 such similar child nodes, and they can be more, if I increase the limit of my search. Also, some of the nodes don't have elements like `<city>sometext</city>`. The code I tried above, doesn't print any attributes or elements that I need. If I don't put the **while loop**, it will print all the attributes and also the elements, but I dont want it to iterate over the attributes where there are no elements like `<city>sometext</city>` and vice versa.

Many thanks!